# Threaded Obj-C code with ARC enabled -- why it works this way?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I need an extra thread in background to listen to requests from socket.

The code is put into a singleton class; it will be called in main.m before NSApplicationMain() like this:

```
 [[SKSocketThread getSingleton] runThread];
```

And runThread is defined as follow:

```
- (void) runThread {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(socketThreadMainLoop:)
                             toTarget:self
                           withObject:[self quitLock]];
}

- (void) socketThreadMainLoop:(id)param {
    NSLock *lock = (NSLock *)param;
    while (![lock tryLock]) {
        NSLog(@"Yay! We are in socketThreadMainLoop now!");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    }
    NSLog(@"Terminating the socket thread...");
    [lock unlock]; // is it really necessary?
}
```

It compiled successfully with no warning, but will throw an error in runtime:

```
autoreleased with no pool in place.
```

I did some googling, tried to pack code in runThread and socketThreadMainLoop with @autoreleasepool, but the error is still there. Finally I wrapped call to runThread with it in main.m, and that worked!

I don't know why it only works this way...

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code with `@autoreleasepool` block.

```
...
- (void) socketThreadMainLoop:(id)param {
@autoreleasepool
{    
    NSLock *lock = (NSLock *)param;
    while (![lock tryLock]) {
        NSLog(@"Yay! We are in socketThreadMainLoop now!");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    }
    NSLog(@"Terminating the socket thread...");
    [lock unlock]; // is it really necessary?
}
}
```

Read more:
[NSAutoreleasePool Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It doesn't work. Instead it will repeat the following error message twice:
    ``objc[64204]: Object 0x100118a00 of class NSLock autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug

    objc[64204]: Object 0x100108c20 of class SKSocketThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug``

Comment: I wonder if it's because I'm using `self` and `quitLock` in the thread.

Comment: Huh?  He is using ARC, not GC.   Therefore an @autoreleasepool{} is very much needed in any secondary threads (that don't directly use run loops).

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on `objc_autoreleaseNoPool` and post the backtrace.  You need an @autoreleasepool{...} in all threads that don't us run loops, including the main thread (in your main.m, if you aren't calling into NSApplicationMain()).

Some additional feedback;  that you named the method `getSingleton` indicates that you are new to iOS development (don't name methods `get*` anything).   That you are using `sleep` in a `while` loop indicates that you are a bit new to the whole networking thing, too.

Also, spinning up a thread prior to the call into `NSApplicationMain()` is totally the wrong thing to do;  you should be doing the networking goop as a normal part of application startup... see below.

You really *really* **really** don't want to do networking using a handrolled while() loop with sleep.   Polling is an awful pattern on mobile devices;  it is battery hungry and that `sleep` is just going to make things unresponsive.

Use a proper run loop and/or dispatch sources and/or CFStream APIs and/or NSFileHandles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really. I will give a try to GCDAsyncSocket -- it seems very promising.

Comment: I took a look at the backtrace, found objc_autoreleaseNoPool is called when I tried to get the quitLock attribute right after setting it in init, which is called by getSingleton(I renamed it as "sharedInstance" now). It's even before my call to runThread which starts the thread...